# Combination of --window-status and --javascript_delay in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I want to use wkhtmltopdf to render both pages I control (in which case I can set the `window.status` when done rendering) and (occasionally) pages I don't control. According to [this thread on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/wkhtmltopdf-general/vWDe5hUAyJ8/2XbXM2g1ZtYJ) I should be able to set `--window-status` to some value, and `--javascript-delay` as well, and rendering starts as soon as either of these conditions is met. That's not my experience; the command `wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 10000 --window-status imdone http://www.google.com/ /tmp/google.pdf` waits forever (version 0.12.3, both on OSX and linux). How can I get the behaviour as described on the mailinglist?

Comment: https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/pull/368

Answer (score 8):

One workaround is to use the `--run-script` tag to set the `window.status` after some time manually -- this works both on the version that uses the patched and that that uses the unpatched QT. Note however that `--run-script` seems to have a small bug in escaping its parameter. Therefore the following line will give you the behaviour requested:

```
wkhtmltopdf --window-status imdone --run-script \
'window.setTimeout(function(){window.status="imdone";},1000);' \
http://google.com/ /tmp/google.pdf
```

Note that because of aforementioned bug, it doesn't work if one puts spaces in the `--run-script` argument, hence the following will not work

```
wkhtmltopdf --window-status imdone --run-script \
'window.setTimeout(function (){window.status = "imdone";}, 1000);' \
http://google.com/ /tmp/google.pdf
```